# Calling variables from main function to other classes & unable to use this?

Tags: c++, variables, inheritance

I was able to run the program when all the classes are placed together in 1 main cpp file with all the classes in it. However, when I split the cpp files into their respective header file and cpp files,there were some errors.

Below are all the files I'm using (They are all in one folder):

```
1) Assignment.cpp  (where the main function is at)
2) ShapeTwoD.cpp (Where the parent class is at)
3) ShapeTwoD.h
3) Square.cpp (Child Class)
4) Square.h
5) Rectangle.cpp (Child class)
6) Rectangle.h
```

**Question 1:**

I have a two variables :

```
ShapeTwoD * Shape2D [100];

int size = 0;
```

The above variables are in the main function. I've tried calling the above variables in the other classes however there is an error that states it is not declared in scope. I've try adding in extern as well however there appears to be some error as well. I've moved the variable to the parent class, Shape2D.cpp, however, the main cpp is unable to detect the variable names. I've also placed in the public: under the parent cpp.

Would be really grateful if someone could help me out as I'm really running out of time. Warmest Regards

**Square.h:**
[image]

**Square.cpp:**

```
class Square: public ShapeTwoD{

    public:

    Square(string name, bool containsWarpSpace, vector < pair<int, int> > vect):ShapeTwoD(name,containsWarpSpace,vect,radius){

        this->vect = vect;
        this->name = name;
        this->containsWarpSpace = containsWarpSpace;


    }
    double computeArea();
    bool isPointOnShape(int x, int y);
    bool isPointInShape(int x, int y);
    vector<pair<int,int> >allCoord();
    void setInnerCoord(vector<pair<int,int> > innerCoord);
    vector<pair<int,int> > getInnerCoord();
    void setOuterCoord(vector<pair<int,int> > outerCoord);
    vector<pair<int,int> > getOuterCoord();
    string toString();
    void calculatePerimeter();

    ~Square(){

    }



};

double Square::computeArea(){

        int width;
        int area;

      std::vector< pair<int, int> >::iterator result = std::max_element(this->vect.begin(), this->vect.end());
      int positionMax = std::distance(this->vect.begin(), result);

       pair<int, int> maxCoordinate = this->vect[positionMax];



    for(int i = 0; i < this->vect.size(); i++){
        if(this->vect[i].second == maxCoordinate.second && this->vect[i] != maxCoordinate){
            width = maxCoordinate.first - this->vect[i].first;
            area = width * width;
        }

    }


    return area;
}

bool Square::isPointOnShape(int x, int y){
     bool result = false;

      std::vector< pair<int, int> >::iterator resultMax = std::max_element(this->vect.begin(), this->vect.end());
          int positionMax = std::distance(this->vect.begin(), resultMax);

          std::vector< pair<int, int> >::iterator resultMin = std::min_element(this->vect.begin(), this->vect.end());
          int positionMin = std::distance(this->vect.begin(), resultMin);

           pair<int, int> maxCoordinate = this->vect[positionMax];
           pair<int, int> minCoordinate = this->vect[positionMin];

           for(int i = 0; i < this->vect.size();i++){

               if(maxCoordinate.first == x || maxCoordinate.second == y || minCoordinate.first == x || minCoordinate.second == y){
                   result = true;
               }
               else{
                   result = false;
               }
           }




    return result;
}
```

**ShapeTwoD.cpp (Parent Class):**

```
class ShapeTwoD{

    protected:
    string name;
    bool containsWarpSpace;
    vector < pair<int, int> > vect;
    int radius;
    double area;
    vector < pair<int, int> > innerCoord;
    vector < pair<int, int> > outerCoord;




    private:


    public:

    ShapeTwoD(){


    }

    ShapeTwoD(string name, bool containsWarpSpace, vector < pair<int, int> > vect, int radius){
        this->radius = radius;
        this->vect = vect;
        this->name = name;
        this->containsWarpSpace = containsWarpSpace;

    }
    virtual double computeArea();
    virtual bool isPointInShape(int x, int y);
    virtual bool isPointOnShape(int x, int y);
    virtual vector<pair<int,int> > allCoord();
    virtual void setInnerCoord(vector<pair<int,int> > innerCord);
    virtual vector<pair<int,int> > getInnerCoord();
    virtual void setOuterCoord(vector<pair<int,int> > outerCoord);
    virtual vector<pair<int,int> > getOuterCoord();
    virtual string toString();
    virtual void calculatePerimeter();

    virtual ~ShapeTwoD(){

    }



    string getName();
    bool getContainsWarpSpace();





    void setName(string name);
    void setContainsWarpSpace(bool containsWarpSpace);


    void setCoord(vector < pair<int, int> > v);
    vector < pair<int, int> > getCoord();
    void setArea(double area);
    double getArea();


};
```

Main Function():

```
int main() {

ShapeTwoD * obj;


int x;
int y;
int radius;

string menu = "0";

while(menu != "5"){
    cout <<"----------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "1) Input sensor data" <<endl;
    cout << "5) Quit\n" <<endl;
    cout << "Please enter your choice:";
    cin >> menu;




if(menu == "1"){

cout << "[ Input sensor data ]" << endl;

    cout << "Please enter name of shape :";
    cin >> shape;
    transform(shape.begin(), shape.end(), shape.begin(), ::tolower);
    cout << "Please enter special type :";
    cin >> specialtype;
    transform(specialtype.begin(), specialtype.end(), specialtype.begin(), ::tolower);



 if(shape == "rectangle"){
     vector < pair<int, int> > temp;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                cout << "Please enter x-ordinate of pt " << i+1 <<" :";
                cin >> x;
                cout << "Please enter y-ordinate of pt " << i+1 << " :";
                cin >> y;

                  std::pair <int,int> p;
                  p = std::make_pair (x,y);
                  temp.push_back(p);

            }


    obj = new Rectangle(shape,"",temp);


      if(specialtype == "ws"){
          obj->setContainsWarpSpace(true);

 }
      else if (specialtype == "ns"){
          obj->setContainsWarpSpace(false);

      }

      Shape2D[size] = obj;
      size ++;
      temp.clear();



    cout << "\nRecords successfully stored. Going back to main menu ...\n" << endl;


    }
else if(shape == "square" ){

     vector < pair<int, int> > temp;

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                cout << "Please enter x-ordinate of pt " << i+1 <<" :";
                cin >> x;
                cout << "Please enter y-ordinate of pt " << i+1 << " :";
                cin >> y;

                  std::pair <int,int> p;
                  p = std::make_pair (x,y);


                temp.push_back(p);


            }

    obj = new Square(shape,"",temp);


      if(specialtype == "ws"){
          obj->setContainsWarpSpace(true);

  }
      else if (specialtype == "ns"){
          obj->setContainsWarpSpace(false);

      }



      temp.clear();
      Shape2D[size] = obj;
      size ++;

    cout << "\nRecords successfully stored. Going back to main menu ...\n" << endl;




}


    cout << "\nRecords successfully stored. Going back to main menu ...\n" << endl;






}
```

Comment: could you place snippets of code that show the main files involved?

Comment: For question 1: Re-read the "static variables" section of your C++ textbook (also use a `std::vector<ShapeTwoD*>`. For question 2: show code.

Comment: Why would you not be able to access `this->vect`in a Shape2D subclass? What error do you get? Also, c++ compilers can deal with nested templates for a while now, you do not need to insert extra spaces anymore.

Comment: Also, if the full class declaration is in your CPP files, what is in your header files?

Comment: Class Square has not member named 'vect'

Comment: What is in ShapeTwoD.h, and do the other files include this header?

Comment: Yes you're right I have added that in the header for all the files except the square. It is working now. However, if I declare a variable at the ShapeTwoD class, how do I call it for the main function class(Assignment.cpp)? It is not part of the inheritance

Comment: Please edit your post with code. I have no idea what you mean by "declare a variable at the shapetwod class" or "call it for the main function class". And please provide a short snippet, not your entire project.

Answer (score 0):

For question one, the most logical place is a static member in `ShapeTwoD`. Put the following in shapetwod.h:

```
class ShapeTwoD {
  public:
    static vector<shared_ptr<ShapeTwoD>> allShapes;
};
```

and put a definition in shapetwod.cpp:

```
vector<shared_ptr<ShapeTwoD>> ShapeTwoD::allShapes;
```

You can then access this vector from elsewhere using `ShapeTwoD::allShapes`.
Note: As of C++17 you can forego the extra definition and make the declaration `inline static`.

Comment: What about accessin through main function?

Comment: In the main function you would also reference `ShapeTwoD::allShapes`.

Comment: outside the main () function?

Comment: Outside the main function you would *ALSO* reference it using `ShapeTwoD::allShapes`. It is a public static member of the ShapeTwoD class and is in scope everywhere `ShapeTwoD` is.

Comment: what about my int variable size? How do I reference that variable at main function so that other classes can use it?

Comment: You don't. You use `ShapeTwoD::allShapes.size()` instead. Although I think you will never need it, as you can walk that vector using iterators or a for-range construct.

Comment: hahaha what If I'm required to use array? That is the reason I've used the size integer

Comment: Should have mentioned that up front. Then just declare two public static variables in your class.

Comment: Yes. Pre-c++17 you need an explicit definition somewhere too, like I posted in my answer. With C++17 you can simply use `inline static int size = 0;`

Comment: what if the calculation of the size is done on the main function?

Comment: Then you access it as `ShapeTwoD::size`. Please re-read your textbook on static variables.